# woocommerce change prices for one country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the prices of 3 products for one country ( switzerland (CH) ).

Is there a way to do this without a plugin? For example to add something to the functions.php to e.g add 5€ to each of the prices if the country is ch?